# How do I locate and add .jar files into iReport?

Tags: java, jar, jasper-reports, ireport

I currently have opened up a .JASPER and .JRXML file in iReport to edit the report. I'm actually simply adding a new field to hold a variable "email".

I set the field and variable up. When i compile however i get these errors.

> Errors compiling
>   \tacmedpdc\users\conference\Desktop\reports\Custom\PackingListTacticalMedical20
>   15.jasper!
>       Compilation exceptions: com.jaspersoft.ireport.designer.compiler.ErrorsCollector
>   @12f1967
>   net.sf.jasperreports.engine.JRException: Errors were encountered when compiling 
>   report expressions class file:
>   1. com.evnt.util.ImageUtil cannot be resolved to a type                     value = com.evnt.util.ImageUtil.decodeImage(((com.evnt.eve.modul    es.ImageModule) ((com.evnt.eve.modules.EVEModule) ((java.lang.Object)parameter_m
>   odule.getValue())).getInstance(com.evnt.eve.modules.ImageModule.class)).getImage
>   Data("Company", 1, true)); //$JR_EXPR_ID=67$

I know that the errors are coming from a lack of .jar files and i do know how to go to "tools" "options" and "set path" but for whatever reason i am unsure of how to locate the .jar files.

Answer (score 0):

You can find the jar under ireport_folder\ireport\modules\ext

Comment: I added the path to " ireport_folder\ireport\modules\ext " but the report is still throwing me the same 24 compile exceptions.